Correspondence email
Can we say "correspondence email" or "email for correspondence", please?
I met this collocation in an invitation to a scientific conference but it sounds weird, IMHO.

Given that email is normally used for correspondence, I agree. "Email address" sounds clearer.

The same constructions are reflected in my work phone number and my phone number for work, where that usage chart makes it pretty obvious we prefer the shorter version. In these contexts, email and phone number are the "base nouns" adjectivally modified by the "noun adjuncts" correspondence and work, which is a common construction in English.

The meaning in this context stems from the practice in science publication of specifying for each paper, editorial, etc., one of its authors as the single individual who has agreed to handle questions and comments about the document, and therefore the person to whom correspondence should be sent.
Thus, what the phrase correspondence email means in this context is “the email address to which the author(s) wish correspondence to be sent.” Out of context, the phrase seems redundant—and one could choose a rephrasing that might be preferable even in context, as your apparent confusion illustrates.

One might say, "please use email for correspondence" but your first example just sounds tautological, as you imply.
